# Is there a function difference similar to vector difference?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let's define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as two functions on the same domain, both functions having the same range. We've also defined $f°g$ as the composition of two functions, namely $f°g$ being equivalent to $f(g(x))$. Is there a difference $h$ being the difference of $f$ and $g$ such that $h = f¤g => g°h = f$?

Comment: I think that $f\circ g$ usually means $f(g(x))$ (ie. first apply $g$, then apply $f$), but I've also seen it defined your way (ie. first apply $f$, then apply $g$)

Comment: @étale-cohomology yes, I've also seen both.